# Python Tkinter: Mis funciones para cambiar variables no funcionan

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy haciendo un programa para programar un apagado del sistema. Y entonces, hice estas variables para diferenciar en que formato el usuario quiere introducir su numero, si es en segundos, minutos, horas o dias

```
inSeconds = False
inMinutes = False
inHours = False
inDays = False
```

Luego de eso cree un par de funciones para establecer que formato usara el usuario

```
def setInSeconds():
    inSeconds = True
    inMinutes = False
    inHours = False
    inDays = False

def setInMinutes():
    inSeconds = False
    inMinutes = True
    inHours = False
    inDays = False

def setInHours():
    inSeconds = False
    inMinutes = False
    inHours = True
    inDays = False

def setInDays():
    inSeconds = False
    inMinutes = False
    inHours = False
    inDays = True
```

Y entonces, cree unos botones para establecerlos (no voy a poner todos los codigos porque es innecesario, solo pongo uno ya que todos son iguales)

Por ejemplo, esto es en segundos:

```
programInSecond = Button(window, text="Segundos", command=setInSeconds)
```

Puse tambien en las funciones, que imprima en la consola si las variables estan en True o False

Luego de eso hice un boton llamado `start` que inicie la cuenta regresiva, la funcion del boton para iniciarla es esta:

```
def start():
print()
print(inSeconds)
print(inMinutes)
print(inHours)
print(inDays)
if (inSeconds == True):
    time = 10
    while time > 0:
        print("FUNCIONA")
        time -= 1
        sleep(1)
    else:
        print("SHUTDOWN")
        subprocess.run("shutdown -r")
```

Tambien (soy mas o menos nuevo en Python, llevo 3 meses) no funciona el metodo del if, while y else, pero eso quiza pueda solucionarlo por mi cuenta, pero si igualmente alguien quiere ayudarme agradezco su ayuda de mas ;)

Mi problema es que por alguna razon, las variables no se ¿"guardan"? (no se como se diria) en su nuevo valor declarado por las funciones `setIn<formato>` ¿Como hago para que se guarden?

Perdon si quiza lo escribi o exprese mal ciertas cosas, pueden preguntar lo que sea, pero ayuda porfavor

Gracias de antemano ;D

EDIT: Dejo el codigo por completo por las dudas:

```
    # Importando librerias #

from tkinter import *
from time import *
import os
import subprocess

# Vars #

global inSeconds
inSeconds = False
global inMinutes
inMinutes = False
global inHours
inHours = False
global inDays
inDays = False

# Funciones #

def setInSeconds():
    inSeconds = True
    inMinutes = False
    inHours = False
    inDays = False
    print()
    print(inSeconds)
    print(inMinutes)
    print(inHours)
    print(inDays)

def setInMinutes():
    inSeconds = False
    inMinutes = True
    inHours = False
    inDays = False
    print()
    print(inSeconds)
    print(inMinutes)
    print(inHours)
    print(inDays)

def setInHours():
    inSeconds = False
    inMinutes = False
    inHours = True
    inDays = False
    print()
    print(inSeconds)
    print(inMinutes)
    print(inHours)
    print(inDays)

def setInDays():
    inSeconds = False
    inMinutes = False
    inHours = False
    inDays = True
    print()
    print(inSeconds)
    print(inMinutes)
    print(inHours)
    print(inDays)

def start():
    print()
    print(inSeconds)
    print(inMinutes)
    print(inHours)
    print(inDays)
    if (inSeconds == True):
        time = 10
        while time > 0:
            print("FUNCIONA")
            time -= 1
            sleep(1)
        else:
            print("SHUTDOWN")
            subprocess.run("shutdown -r")
    
    if (inMinutes == True):
        if (time == 1):
            time = 60
            while (time > 0):
                time -= 1
                sleep(1)
                if (time <= 0):
                    os.system("shutdown /r /t 0")
        if (time == 2):
            time = 120
            while (time > 0):
                time -= 1
                sleep(1)
                if (time <= 0):
                    os.system("shutdown /r /t 0")
        if (time == 3):
            time = 180
            while (time > 0):
                time -= 1
                sleep(1)
                if (time <= 0):
                    os.system("shutdown /r /t 0")
        if (time == 4):
            time = 240
            while (time > 0):
                time -= 1
                sleep(1)
                if (time <= 0):
                    os.system("shutdown /r /t 0")
        if (time == 5):
            time = 300
            while (time > 0):
                time -= 1
                sleep(1)
                if (time <= 0):
                    os.system("shutdown /r /t 0")
        if (time == 6):
            time = 360
            while (time > 0):
                time -= 1
                sleep(1)
                if (time <= 0):
                    os.system("shutdown /r /t 0")
        if (time == 7):
            time = 420
            while (time > 0):
                time -= 1
                sleep(1)
                if (time <= 0):
                    os.system("shutdown /r /t 0")
        if (time == 8):
            time = 480
            while (time > 0):
                time -= 1
                sleep(1)
                if (time <= 0):
                    os.system("shutdown /r /t 0")
        if (time == 9):
            time = 540
            while (time > 0):
                time -= 1
                sleep(1)
                if (time <= 0):
                    os.system("shutdown /r /t 0")
        if (time == 10):
            time = 600
            while (time > 0):
                time -= 1
                sleep(1)
                if (time <= 0):
                    os.system("shutdown /r /t 0")
        if (time == 11):
            time = 660
            while (time > 0):
                time -= 1
                sleep(1)
                if (time <= 0):
                    os.system("shutdown /r /t 0")
        if (time == 12):
            time = 720
            while (time > 0):
                time -= 1
                sleep(1)
                if (time <= 0):
                    os.system("shutdown /r /t 0")
        if (time == 13):
            time = 780
            while (time > 0):
                time -= 1
                sleep(1)
                if (time <= 0):
                    os.system("shutdown /r /t 0")
        if (time == 14):
            time = 840
            while (time > 0):
                time -= 1
                sleep(1)
                if (time <= 0):
                    os.system("shutdown /r /t 0")
        if (time == 15):
            time = 900
            while (time > 0):
                time -= 1
                sleep(1)
                if (time <= 0):
                    os.system("shutdown /r /t 0")
        if (time == 16):
            time = 960
            while (time > 0):
                time -= 1
                sleep(1)
                if (time <= 0):
                    os.system("shutdown /r /t 0")
        if (time == 17):
            time = 1020
            while (time > 0):
                time -= 1
                sleep(1)
                if (time <= 0):
                    os.system("shutdown /r /t 0")
        if (time == 18):
            time = 1080
            while (time > 0):
                time -= 1
                sleep(1)
                if (time <= 0):
                    os.system("shutdown /r /t 0")
        if (time == 19):
            time = 1140
            while (time > 0):
                time -= 1
                sleep(1)
                if (time <= 0):
                    os.system("shutdown /r /t 0")
        if (time == 20):
            time = 1200
            while (time > 0):
                time -= 1
                sleep(1)
                if (time <= 0):
                    os.system("shutdown /r /t 0")
    #elif (inHours == True):
    #    if (time == 1):


    # Setup #

    window = Tk()
    window.geometry("385x250")
    window.title("PCOFF")

    # Codigo #

    welcome = Label(window, text="- - PCOFF - -")
    welcome.configure(font=("Arial", 15), fg="red")
    welcome.pack()
    welcome.place(x= 135, y= 5)

    instructions = Label(window, text="Seleccione en que formato quieres 
    programar su apagado/reiniciado")
    instructions.pack()
    instructions.place(x= 8, y= 30)

    program = Entry(window, width=20)
    program.pack()
    program.place(x= 30, y= 70)

    programInSecond = Button(window, text="Segundos", 
    command=setInSeconds)
    programInSecond.pack()
    programInSecond.place(x= 30, y= 100)

    programInMinutes = Button(window, text="Minutos", 
    command=setInMinutes)
    programInMinutes.pack()
    programInMinutes.place(x= 100, y= 100)

    programInHours = Button(window, text="  Horas  ", 
    command=setInHours)
    programInHours.pack()
    programInHours.place(x= 33, y= 130)

    programInDays = Button(window, text="   Dias   ", command=setInDays)
    programInDays.pack()
    programInDays.place(x= 100, y= 130)

    startCountdown = Button(window, text="    Iniciar    ", 
    command=start)
    startCountdown.configure(bg="green")
    startCountdown.pack()
    startCountdown.place(x= 58, y= 170)

    stopCountdown = Button(window, text="     Parar     ")
    stopCountdown.configure(bg="red")
    stopCountdown.pack()
    stopCountdown.place(x= 58, y= 200)

    # mainloop #
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Deberías publicar todo el código para que te podamos ayudar correctamente....

Comment: Ok, ahora la modifico

Comment: @Alexci el código completo es innecesario, a simple vista se ve el error

Comment: Las variables en una función son creadas y destruidas en la misma función, si lo que deseas es modificar el valor de una variable que no esté en la función entonces debes de declararla variable como `global` **dentro de la función**

Comment: Pero seso tendria que hacerlo dentro de cada funcion? El programa va a funcionar si hao eso? Gracias igualmente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al margen de lo que preguntas sobre el uso de globales, hay varias cosas mejorables en tu código, y un error importante que hay que corregir.

## Problema de diseño y de concepto

Primero el error. No puedes (no debes) usar `time.sleep()` dentro de un programa con Tk, porque eso detiene durante un tiempo (1 segundo en tu caso) la interfaz de usuario. Durante ese segundo, el usuario no podrá interactuar con la interfaz que quedará como "congelada" (el sistema operativo mostrará algún indicador, tipo un reloj de arena, un spinner, algo que cualquier usuario identificará como "el sistema está ocupado").

En ese tiempo, aunque el usuario pulse el botón "Parar", ese botón no reflejará la interacción porque está congelado durante ese segundo. Sólo cuando el segundo pase tendrá la interfaz de usuario oportunidad de responder, si es que tu código devuelve el control a Tk en algún momento. Pero lo peor es que no devuelves el control, pues ese `time.sleep()` está dentro de un bucle `while`.

Dicho de otro modo, cuando el usuario pulsa "Iniciar", se invoca la función `start()` y hasta que esa función no retorne, el usuario no podrá seguir interactuando con la interfaz. No podrá pulsar botones, ni siquiera el botón "Parar". Y como bien sabes, tu función `start()` no retorna, pues una vez el bucle llega a su final, el sistema se reinicia. No es posible para el usuario abortar la cuenta atrás una vez empezada.

La solución es un tanto compleja. Tu función `start()` no puede quedarse esperando a que pase el tiempo. Por el contrario, debe retornar lo antes posible, dejando encargado a Tk que 1 segundo más tarde llame a otra función (que será la que decrementará el contador, y encargará de nuevo a Tk que la llame 1 segundo más tarde, etc.) Para encargar a Tk que llame a otra función pasado 1 segundo se usaría `window.after(1000, funcion)` (1000 es el tiempo que se mide en milisegundos).

Esto hace necesario cambiar por completo la arquitectura de tu aplicación.

La idea sería tener un booleano que indique si estamos en medio de una cuenta atrás o no. La función `start()` se limitaría a poner `True` en ese booleano, y llamar a `window.after(1000, contar)`, tras lo cual retorna. Eso garantiza que la interfaz de usuario no se queda congelada.

Un segundo más tarde, Tk llamará a la función `contar()` tal como le hemos pedido. Esa función decrementará el contador (opcionalmente podría mostrar el valor que tiene, para que el usuario vea cuánto tiempo falta para el apagado), mirará si llegó a 0 en cuyo caso realiza el apagado, y si no  usará de nuevo `window.after(1000, contar)` para encargar que 1 segundo más tarde se invoque de nuevo. Pero esto sólo lo hará si el booleano que indica que estamos en mitad de una cuenta vale `True`. Si por el contrario vale `False`, retorna sin dejar encargada su próxima invocación.

La función `parar()` se limita por tanto a poner ese booleano a `False`.

Es decir, la idea general sería algo como:

```
def start():
   contando = True
   window.after(1000, contar)

def stop():
   contando = False

def contar():
    if not contando:
        return
    time = time - 1
    display_time()
    if time <= 0:
       reiniciar()
    else:
       window.after(1000, contar)
```

## Mejoras de diseño del código

Aparte del problema anterior, otras mejoras importantes que se pueden hacer serían:

- Cambiar la implementación para que use una clase. Todas las variables globales serían entonces atributos (`self.time` para el contador, `self.contando` para el booleano que indica si tenemos una cuenta, etc.). Todas las funciones serían métodos de la clase que podrían acceder a esos atributos. De este modo se evita el uso de variables globales.
- Toda la larga serie de `if` que tienes para convertir los minutos en segundos se puede simplificar enormemente. Basta tener un diccionario de unidades que diga cuántos segundos hay en un minuto, hora, etc. Por ejemplo:

```
units = {
    "Segundos": 1,
    "Minutos": 60,
    "Horas": 60*60,
    "Dias": 24*60*60
}
```

Entonces todos tus `if` se reducen a una línea:

```
tiempo = tiempo * units[unidad]
```

Así, si `unidad` es "Horas"`,` units[unidad]`será 3600, y de ese modo multiplicas lo que había en`time` (número de horas) por 3600 y así queda convertido en segundos.

## Juntando todo

La siguiente es una implementación completa de las diferentes ideas que he ido dando más arriba. Usa una clase para contener todos los métodos y variables, he añadido otra Label para mostrar debajo la cuenta atrás en segundos, y he hecho uso del conversor de unidades para reducir el código. Eso elimina todas las variables booleanas `inSeconds`, etc. así como las funciones `setInSeconds()`, etc.

Ahora todos los botones de cambio de unidades activan una misma función: `get_time()` que extrae del `Entry` el valor que haya escrito el usuario (poniendo por defecto 1 si no escribió nada), y le aplica la conversión de unidades que corresponda. Esta creación de botones la hago en un bucle, pues prácticamente la misma para todos.

He implementado también la funcionalidad de parar el contador. He quitado la línea que realiza el shutdown, para que no me apagara el ordenador durante las pruebas, y la he sustituido por un `print()` para que se vea cuándo llega al final.

```
from tkinter import *
from time import *
import os
import subprocess

# Vars #
class App:
    # Variables
    def __init__(self):
        self.units = {       # Factores de conversión a segundos
            "Segundos": 1,
            "Minutos": 60,
            "Horas": 60*60,
            "Dias": 24*60*60
        }
        self.time = 0
        self.contando = False

    def set_time(self, unit):
        """Este método toma el tiempo introducido por el usuario,
        lo pasa a segundos según el botón pulsado, y lo deja
        en self.time

        Este método es invocado al pulsar uno de los botones de unidades"""
        try:
            self.time = int(self.time_entry.get())
        except:
            self.time = 1

        self.time = self.time * self.units.get(unit, 1)
        self.display_time()  # Mostrar el valor inicial del contador

    def display_time(self):
        """Este método muestra el valor del contador en una label"""
        self.time_label["text"] = str(self.time)

    def contar(self):
        """Aquí es donde se decrementa el contador y se llama a reiniciar()
        cuando el contador llega a cero. Pero la función no espera bloqueando
        la interfaz de usuario, sino que usa tk.after para programar su
        próxima ejecución.
        """
        if not self.contando:
            return
        self.time = self.time - 1
        self.display_time()
        if self.time <= 0:
            self.reiniciar()
        self.window.after(1000, self.contar)

    def reiniciar(self):
        """Aquí se implementaría el shutdown"""
        self.contando = False  # Parar la cuenta lo primero
        print("FIN DE LA CUENTA")
        # Comando para shutdown

    def start(self):
        """Comenzar la cuenta atrás (al pulsar botón 'Iniciar')"""
        self.contando = True
        self.window.after(1000, self.contar)

    def stop(self):
        """Detener la cuenta atrás (al pulsar el botón 'Parar')"""
        self.contando = False

    def setup_gui(self):
        """Creación de la interfaz de usuario"""

        window = Tk()
        window.geometry("385x280")
        window.title("PCOFF")

        welcome = Label(window, text="- - PCOFF - -")
        welcome.configure(font=("Arial", 15), fg="red")
        welcome.pack()
        welcome.place(x= 135, y= 5)

        instructions = Label(window, text="Seleccione en que formato quiere\n"
                             "programar su apagado/reiniciado")
        instructions.pack()
        instructions.place(x= 8, y= 30)

        # Uso self. para guardar los componentes que necesito acceder desde
        # otros métodos

        self.time_entry = Entry(window, width=20)
        self.time_entry.pack()
        self.time_entry.place(x= 30, y= 70)

        # Guardo también los botones, aunque luego no lo uso. Pero podría servir
        # para desactivarlos todos mientras esté activa la cuenta atrás, por ejemplo
        self.botones_unidades = []
        for i, unit in enumerate(self.units):
            button = Button(window, text=unit, command=lambda x=unit: self.set_time(x))
            button.pack()
            x = 30 + (i%2)*70
            y = 100 + (i//2)*30
            button.place(x=x, y=y)
            self.botones_unidades.append(button)

        self.boton_start = Button(window, text="    Iniciar    ", command=self.start)
        self.boton_start.configure(bg="green")
        self.boton_start.pack()
        self.boton_start.place(x= 58, y= 170)

        self.boton_stop = Button(window, text="     Parar     ", command=self.stop)
        self.boton_stop.configure(bg="red")
        self.boton_stop.pack()
        self.boton_stop.place(x= 58, y= 200)

        # Label donde mostrar el temporizador
        self.time_label = Label(window, text="- - -")
        self.time_label.configure(font=("Arial", 15), fg="red")
        self.time_label.pack()
        self.time_label.place(x= 135, y= 230)

        self.window = window # Para poder usarlo desde otros métodos

    def run_mainloop(self):
        self.window.mainloop()

# Programa principal
app = App()
app.setup_gui()
app.run_mainloop()
```

### Edit

A petición del usuario incluyo la versión "sin clases" que es exactamente igual a la anterior, pero convirtiendo en variables globales todas aquellas que deben ser compartidas por las funciones, y eliminando `self` de todas partes.

```
from tkinter import *
from time import *
import os
import subprocess

units = {  # Factores de conversión a segundos
    "Segundos": 1,
    "Minutos": 60,
    "Horas": 60 * 60,
    "Dias": 24 * 60 * 60,
}
time = 0
contando = False

def set_time(unit):
    """Este método toma el tiempo introducido por el usuario,
    lo pasa a segundos según el botón pulsado, y lo deja
    en time

    Este método es invocado al pulsar uno de los botones de unidades"""
    global time

    try:
        time = int(time_entry.get())
    except:
        time = 1

    time = time * units.get(unit, 1)
    display_time()  # Mostrar el valor inicial del contador

def display_time():
    """Este método muestra el valor del contador en una label"""
    time_label["text"] = str(time)

def contar():
    """Aquí es donde se decrementa el contador y se llama a reiniciar()
    cuando el contador llega a cero. Pero la función no espera bloqueando
    la interfaz de usuario, sino que usa tk.after para programar su
    próxima ejecución.
    """
    global time
    if not contando:
        return
    time = time - 1
    display_time()
    if time <= 0:
        reiniciar()
    window.after(1000, contar)

def reiniciar():
    """Aquí se implementaría el shutdown"""
    global contando
    contando = False  # Parar la cuenta lo primero
    print("FIN DE LA CUENTA")
    # Comando para shutdown

def start():
    """Comenzar la cuenta atrás (al pulsar botón 'Iniciar')"""
    global contando
    contando = True
    window.after(1000, contar)

def stop():
    """Detener la cuenta atrás (al pulsar el botón 'Parar')"""
    global contando
    contando = False

def setup_gui():
    """Creación de la interfaz de usuario"""
    global window, time_entry, time_label
    window = Tk()
    window.geometry("385x280")
    window.title("PCOFF")

    welcome = Label(window, text="- - PCOFF - -")
    welcome.configure(font=("Arial", 15), fg="red")
    welcome.pack()
    welcome.place(x=135, y=5)

    instructions = Label(
        window,
        text="Seleccione en que formato quiere\nprogramar su apagado/reiniciado",
    )
    instructions.pack()
    instructions.place(x=8, y=30)

    # Uso  para guardar los componentes que necesito acceder desde
    # otros métodos

    time_entry = Entry(window, width=20)
    time_entry.pack()
    time_entry.place(x=30, y=70)

    # Guardo también los botones, aunque luego no lo uso. Pero podría servir
    # para desactivarlos todos mientras esté activa la cuenta atrás, por ejemplo
    botones_unidades = []
    for i, unit in enumerate(units):
        button = Button(
            window, text=unit, command=lambda x=unit: set_time(unit=x)
        )
        button.pack()
        x = 30 + (i % 2) * 70
        y = 100 + (i // 2) * 30
        button.place(x=x, y=y)
        botones_unidades.append(button)

    boton_start = Button(window, text="    Iniciar    ", command=start)
    boton_start.configure(bg="green")
    boton_start.pack()
    boton_start.place(x=58, y=170)

    boton_stop = Button(window, text="     Parar     ", command=stop)
    boton_stop.configure(bg="red")
    boton_stop.pack()
    boton_stop.place(x=58, y=200)

    # Label donde mostrar el temporizador
    time_label = Label(window, text="- - -")
    time_label.configure(font=("Arial", 15), fg="red")
    time_label.pack()
    time_label.place(x=135, y=230)

def run_mainloop():
    window.mainloop()


# Programa principal
setup_gui()
run_mainloop()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, pero el problema es que yo no se usar clases aun, y si yo quiero modificarlo no sabria como hacerlo. Si no es molestia ¿Hay alguna foma de hacerlo sin clases?

Comment: Y otra pregunta, en la parte en la que me dices que todos mis if se pueden limitar a uno (que me has dicho que use esto: "tiempo = tiempo * units[unidad]"). En "[unidad] ¿Tengo que poner mis variables o poner "Segundos" o "Minutos" etcétera o como?

Comment: El código que te he puesto al final se puede convertir a "código sin clases" sin más que quitar `class App` al inicio, modificar todas las funciones para quitarles el parámetro `self`, quitar todos los `self.` delante de los nombres de las variables, y hacer todas esas variables globales (te vas a hinchar a poner `global` dentro de todas las funciones :-) La parte que va en el `__init__()` sería la que inicializa esas variables, fuera de toda función. El "programa principal" se convertiría en `setup_gui()` y después `run_mainloop()`

Comment: He añadido a la respuesta la versión "sin clases". Pero te animo a que compares ambas para que veas que la programación con clases no es tan diferente (al menos en este caso) y te ayuda a tener mejor organizado el código.

Comment: En cuanto a la conversión de unidades, he cambiado el `units[unit]` por `units.get(unit, 1)`, que es lo mismo sólo que si la unidad pedida no está en el diccionario, en vez de una excepción te devuelve 1. Esto lo uso en la función `set_time()` como puedes observar. Esa función recibe como parámetro `unit` que sería una cadena como `"Minutos"`. y ese parámetro se lo pasa la lambda que hay en la asignación del botón.

Comment: Muchas gracias por toda tu ayuda! Si pronto empezare a aprender clases :D

Comment: Tengo otra pregunta, agrege un OptionMenu() para alternar si el usuario quiere apagar o reiniciar el sistema. Si el OptionMenu esta en 'Apagar', el sistema se apagara, de hecho eso agrege, un if que comoruebe eso, tambien agrege otro para hacer la comprobacion con 'Reiniciar', pero aun asi no funciona ¿Por que no fdunciona? ¿Es algo similar a lo de mis variables de Segundos, minutos, horas, y dias? Si quieres que haga una pregunta por si no lo entiendes dimelo

Comment: No puedo adivinar por qué no funciona sin ver el código :-) Pero perfectamente podría ser porque hayas olvidado poner esas variables como globales. Cuando una función modifica una variable, si no declara previamente que es global, estará creando una copia local que no afecta a la variable global. Quizás sea mejor que hagas una pregunta nueva para verlo.